# Why do game developers implement 3 share buttons in 1 game app

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, shared, game-center-leaderboard

I understand the separate share button for Facebook and another button for Twitter. But in GameCenter's Leaderboards, there's also a share button that does the same thing as the implemented separate FaceBook/Twitter buttons. What's the point of implementing the separate shared FB/Twitter button if it's on GameCenter's Leaderboards?

Comment: Presumably these game developers are writing cross-platform code and other platforms don't offer GameCenter.

Comment: What you mean? You mean like the game is for iPhone and then also for Android. They do it because Android doesn't offer game center or a shared button in Google's Play version of Game Center?

Comment: Yes. This means that the designers only have to design a screen once. It is also possible that they're using Cordova (or something similar) that allows them to write the source code once. If the source says "show a button", it'll show that button. The platform is abstracted.